# Сообщение для сброса пароля

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с кодом, не могу понять почему не работает уведомления об успехе или не успехе сброса пароля переменная

Вот сам код страницы php

```php
<main class="main-site">
    <div class="screen screen--login screen--forget">
      <div class="screen__content">
        <div class="block-login">
          <div class="login__text-reg mod--foreget">Вспомнили пароль? <a href="/login" class="link">Войти</a></div>
          <h1 class="page-heading1 heading--foreget">Забыли пароль?</h1>
          <div class="w-formw">





            <?
            if(isset($_POST['do_reset'])) {
            $email = protect($_POST['remail']);
            $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");
            $select_in = $sql->fetch_array();
            $email_inbase = $select_in['email'];



/* Здесь должна быть не успешная первая*/ 
            if(empty($email)){
              echo"<div data-clipboard-target='#wf-form-forget-form'>Вы не ввели адрес электронной почты</div>";}

/* Здесь вторая не успешная*/ 
              elseif ($email_inbase !== $email) { echo "<div id='submit' data-clipboard-target='#wf-form-forget-form'>Адрес электронной почты у нас не зарегистрирован</div>"; }

    /* Здесь третья не успешная*/           
            elseif(!verifMail($email)) { echo "<div id='submit' data-clipboard-target='#wf-form-forget-form'>Введите корректный email адрес</div>"; }
            else {

/* Здесь четвертая не успешная*/ 
            # Каптча
            if(!isset($_POST["capth"]) || $_POST["capth"] !== $_SESSION['captcha']) {
              echo err_msg("<div id='submit' data-clipboard-target='#wf-form-forget-form'>Антибот проверка (Captcha) не пройдена</div>"); }else{

            function gen($leight){

                $x = '';

                $str = "qwertyuiopasdfghjkzxcvbnm1234567890ABCDEFGKMNVYU";

                for($i=0; $i<$leight; $i++){
                    $x .= substr($str, mt_rand(0, strlen($str)-1), 1);
                }

                return $x;
            }

            $mepas = gen(10);

            $mepas_md5 = md5($mepas);
            $sql = $mysqli->query("UPDATE users SET pass='$mepas_md5' WHERE email = '$email'");

            $mailtext = '<div><img src="assets/images/logo.svg"></div>
            <br/>
            Уважаемый участник - <span style="color: #E77225; text-decoration: none;">'.$email.'</span>, вы заказали восстановление пароля.
            <br/>
            Так как у нас установлено шифрование паролей, мы не можем показать ваш старый пароль, поэтому специально для вас был сгенерирован новый.<br><br>
            Ваш новый пароль - <b><span style="background: #388be3; color: #fff; text-decoration: none; padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;">'.$mepas.'</span></b>
            <br><br>
            Воспользоваться им вы можете при входе на сайт, с Уважением администрация <b><a href="http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'" style="color: #388be3; text-decoration: none;">'.$nameSite.'</a></b>
            <br><br>
            --
            <br>
            <span style="font-size: 75%">Это сообщение отправлено вам автоматически, пожалуйста не отвечайте на него.
            <br>
            Если вам нужно связаться со службой поддержки наши контакты здесь <a href="http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/about#tab2" style="color: #388be3; text-decoration: none;">контакты</a>.
            <br>
            Если письмо отправлено вам по ошибке, просто проигнорируйте его.
            <br>
            Подробнее узнать о проекте и оформить подписку на новости вы можете посетив <a href="http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'" style="color: #388be3; text-decoration: none;">наш проект</a></span>';
            $headers="Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
            $headers.="From: ".$mail_project;
            mail($email, "Восстановление пароля", $mailtext, $headers); {

              /* Здесь успешная*/ 
              echo "<div id='submit' data-clipboard-target='#wf-form-forget-form'>Вам отправлено письмо с паролем</div>";
            }
            }
            }
            }
            ?>

            <form action="" method="POST" id="form" name="form" class="form-login">
              <div class="wrap-input wrap--login">
                <label for="E-mail">Укажите e-mail учетной записи</label>
                <input type="text" class="input input--login w-input" name="remail" maxlength="40" placeholder="<?=$mail_project?>"></div>
                <div class="wrap-input wrap--login">
                    <label for="login">
                      <img src="/captcha.php?size=80/40/20"  border="0" class="img-capth"/> Введите Captcha </label>
                    <input maxlength="5" type="textt" name="capth" id="captcha" class="input input--login w-input" placeholder="12345">
                </div>
              <input type="submit" value="Восстановить" class="button w-button" name="do_reset" id="Submit">
            </form>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="login__wrap-bg"></div>
    </div>
  </main>
```

/* Ниже сам скрипт который должен отвечать за успех или не успех и выводить соответствующие сообщение*/

```js
  <script>

      function notyOpen(message, type, timeout, url, redirect)
      {
          new Noty({
              type: type,
              theme: 'metroui',
              text: message,
              timeout: timeout,
              layout: "topLeft",
              closeWith: ['click']
          }).show();

          if(timeout == false)  setTimeout("location='"+url+"';", redirect);

          return false;
      }

      $("#wf-form-forget-form").on("submit", function(){

          var mail = $('#email').val();

          $.post(

              '/?request=recovery', {
                  doctype: true,
                  mail: mail
              }, function(data) {

                  if (data.result == 'OK') notyOpen(data.message, 'success', 4000, '', false);
                  else notyOpen(data.message, 'error', 4000, '', false);

              }, 'json');

          return false;
      });
      </script>
```

помогите разобраться с этой проблемой!

если все правильно завязать должно получиться на выходе так
[image: если все правильно завязать должно получиться на выходе так]

Comment: Возможно дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-php-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5)

Comment: У Вас просто мешанина в коде, с рядом неопределенных переменных, которые непонятно откуда берутся, лишними фигурными скобками и JS кодом, который не имеет отношения к приведенному выше HTML формы.

Comment: Код функционирует все отлично! единственное нужно как то встроить в переменную вывод  уведомлений от сайта определенным скриптом что в низу указан! если можешь помоги пожалуйста!

Comment: Что именно функционирует? Тот скрипт что внизу, не имеет особого отношения к коду приведенному выше. В приведенном коде нет элемента с таким ID `wf-form-forget-form`, как и нет инпута с ID `email`, а сабмит формы вызывает какую-то неизвестную функцию `contact()` на клик `onclick="contact();"`

Comment: у вас 8 ошибок в слове "проблема"

Comment: Ну я и обратилась к вам за помощью, помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Для начала надо убрать SQL инъекции. Нет смысла делать хоть какую-то защиту, если кто угодно сможет авторизоваться без пароля, и заодно увести пароли всех остальных пользователей.

Comment: Где??? подскажи пожалуйста!

Comment: 1. `$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");`, 2. `$mysqli->query("UPDATE users SET pass='$mepas_md5' WHERE email = '$email'");`

Comment: Так в общем мне и ни кто не поможет!(((( плакать охота!